# How can I execute multiple queries in one query?

Tags: sqlite

I am building a chat application where I am using Firebase to send and receive messages. Once I send or receive a message, I am storing it to SQLite as follows. Now it the recent chats screen, I need the last message from all the unique chats, number of unread messages in those unique chats in one single query as I am observing the SQLite database.

```
Mid(STRING)     | SentBy | SentTo | message | readTime | sentTime| Type
----------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+---------+------
A               | AA     | JD     | M1      |   1      |    0    |  S
B               | JD     | AA     | M2      |   2      |    1    |  s
C               | AA     | JD     | M3      |   3      |    2    |  s
D               | AB     | JD     | m5      |   null   |    3    |  s
E               | AA     | JC     | M1      |   5      |    4    |  s
F               | JD     | AB     | M2      |   6      |    5    |  s
G               | AA     | JD     | M3      |   7      |    6    |  s
H               | AA     | JC     | m5      |   8      |    7    |  s
I               | AA     | JD     | M1      |   null   |    8    |  s
J               | JD     | AA     | M2      |  10      |    9    |  s
K               | AA     | JD     | M3      |  11      |    10   |  s
L               | AB     | JC     | m5      |  12      |    11   |  s
M               | AA     | JD     | M1      |  13      |    12   |  s
N               | JC     | AA     | M2      |  14      |    13   |  s
O               | AB     | JD     | M3      |  15      |    14   |  s
P               | JC     | JD     | m5      |  16      |    15   |  s
```

I tried

```
SELECT *,COUNT() FROM messagesTable GROUP BY min ( sentBy, sentTo ), max( sentBy , sentTo ) ORDER BY sentTime desc
```

This query gives me the last messages from every combination of sentTo and sentBy. But I also need to know how many messages are unread for that combination. I want to run a query for every row like

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM messagesTable WHERE sentBy = message.sentBy, sentTo = message.sentTo, readTime = null
```

How can I run both queries in a single query?

Comment: Are you using sqlite 3.25 or newer?

Comment: I am not very sure

Comment: @VnsAditya note that your first query as it stands may not give the latest message per conversation in output as you require.

Comment: @VnsAditya there was a bounty for this answer, is it revoked?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must group by the combination of `(sentby, sentto)` and with a straight `count(*)` get the total number of messages and with conditional aggregation you can get the number of unread mesages.
Then join to the result to the table to get also the last message:

```
select 
  g.user1, g.user2, g.lasttime, m.message lastmessage, 
  g.totalcounter, g.unreadcounter
from messagestable m inner join (
  select 
    min(sentby, sentto) user1, max(sentby, sentto) user2,
    max(senttime) lasttime, count(*) totalcounter,
    sum(case when readtime is null then 1 else 0 end) unreadcounter
  from messagestable
  group by user1, user2
) g 
on g.user1 = min(m.sentby, m.sentto) and g.user2 = max(m.sentby, m.sentto) 
and g.lasttime = m.senttime
order by g.lasttime desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/CfMrXW2DHGQQyqjR2r5oT/2).
Results:

```
| user1 | user2 | lasttime | lastmessage | totalcounter | unreadcounter |
| ----- | ----- | -------- | ----------- | ------------ | ------------- |
| JC    | JD    | 15       | m5          | 1            | 0             |
| AB    | JD    | 14       | M3          | 3            | 1             |
| AA    | JC    | 13       | M2          | 3            | 0             |
| AA    | JD    | 12       | M1          | 8            | 1             |
| AB    | JC    | 11       | m5          | 1            | 0             |
```

Comment: Note that the OP stated that they want the latest message per each conversation in output too.